# want to add a simple navigation bar in tab bar view controller

Tags: uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I created a tab bar controller with 4 customized tab bar items. I want to add navigation bars (the simple banner with only a title on it) to 2 of the tab bar view controllers. 
This is what I did. 
let's say the 4 tab bar view controllers are vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4.
I add some codes in the viewDidLoad() under the file vc1ViewController.m

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
navBar.topItem.title = @"News";
UINavigationItem *title = [[UINavigationItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"news"];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

I also add a tableview later

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tv];
```

When i run the app, the table could be shown, but the navigation bar is not there.

What could i do to fix it? i just wanna a simple navigation bar with a title.

Comment: thanks guys. i tried to drag a navigation bar to one of the xib files and it appeared. So i think maybe i could just add a navigation bar by code, too. It seems I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a UINavigationController (which is a special ViewController and set that for the tab.) This will create the navigationbar for you. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)

Comment: thanks man. One more question, i changed the view controllers into UINavigationController. The navigation bar showed. Now i add a title by adding this simple code in the viewDidLoad() under nav1.m "self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"news";" NO TITLE APPEARED

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the viewcontollers of the tab bar to navigation controllers that contain the view controllers you want.

So instead of using vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4 for the tab bar, use nav1, nav2, nav3, nav4 shown below:

```
 UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
 UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
 UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];
 UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc4];
```

From there you can set a title with:

```
[vc1 setTitle:@"title1"];
[vc2 setTitle:@"title2"];
[vc3 setTitle:@"title3"];
[vc4 setTitle:@"title4"];
```

As explained in the [UINavigationController Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/):

> If no custom title view is set, the navigation bar displays a label containing the view controller’s default title. The string for this label is usually obtained from the title property of the view controller itself. If you want to display a different title than the one associated with the view controller, set the title property of the view controller’s navigation item instead.

Comment: thanks man. One more question, i changed the view controllers into UINavigationController. The navigation bar showed. Now i add a title by adding this simple code in the viewDidLoad() under nav1.m "self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"news";"       NO TITLE APPEARED

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it still showed no title. I also read the UINavigationController Docs. Interesting.